# Propositional Logic Puzzle

Tags: propositional-calculus, puzzle

"There is an island with two mythical creatures, the Komos and the Dragos. Komos loves eating visitors to the island while Dragos hates to eat visitors. One fine day, you mysteriously end up on the island and encounter two creatures, Blue and Red. The Blue creature smiles and tell you, “Don’t be afraid! We both are not human eaters”. Determine, if possible, whether the Blue and Red creatures is a Komos or a Dragos."

I found the scenario given is too straight forward, as it doesn't state any possible liar.
What I comprehend from this scenario will be, Let p indicates Blue is Dragos, q indicates Red is Dragos. Since Blue doesn't eat humans, and it doesn't lie, so if p then q, both Blue and Red are Dragos.

Would like to here more thoughts from you all.

Comment: Where do you get that Blue doesn't lie?

Comment: I mean, he's lying... since one of the two is a human eater... and presumably only the human eater would want you to feel safe when you're very much *not*.  So I would guess that Blue is Komos and Red is Dragos.

Comment: Also, unfortunately the parsing of the creature's statement is ambiguous.  "We both are not human eaters" could mean "Neither of us eats humans" or "It is not true that both of us eat humans" or "Neither of us is human, and we are eaters".

Comment: Are there two creatures or two kinds of creature? The last sentence of the quotation suggests it means two kinds, the rest of the quotation is unclear: has it suffered in translation?

Comment: Furthermore, "Dragos hates to eat visitors" doesn't mean that it *doesn't* eat them, just that it hates to do so.

Comment: Indeed, Dragos may absolutely love *watching* visitors be eaten.

Comment: I assume it's not lying cause it's not stated in the scenario, which I found it odd because this kind of propositional logic puzzle will usually provide it with more details of the character.